# How to paint a circle pattern on a big piece of paper

Tags: paper, paint, automation

I need some ideas on how to make a circle pattern on a large piece of paper, e.g. A0 ISO format.

I have searched for a special paint roller online but in my case the circles must be 60mm equaly spaced and this seems to be too specific, so I think I'll have to develop my own tool to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could buy some sheets of 60mm round stickers, but that is shopping not a hack. Or go to a print shop and get the sheet made for you.

Comment: How accurate does it have to be, and do you want to paint or draw the circles?

Comment: @Hobbes The circles must be roughly the same size, no need to be extremely accurate. Either paint or draw, since the circles' job is just to mark the spot where I should glue some disk shaped objects.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest method:

1. in a drawing program, create an A0-sized document and draw the circles where you want them. I'd draw one circle, copy it, then copy both of them until you have one row, then copy/paste that row. Use the Align and Distribute tools to get an even pattern.
2. Send to a print shop to be printed on A0.

The cheapest method:

1. Along the edges of the paper, mark where you want the centerlines of the circles to be.
2. Draw lines between those centerline marks.
3. Use calipers to draw circles around each point where two lines cross.

Answer (score 1):

Find something, like a jar or tin can, that has a 60mm diameter and dip it in a shallow tray of paint then press it onto the paper. If the cans are cheap, glue several together (hot melt glue gun?) with a dedicated spacer (bits of wood cut to the length you want?) so you can stamp several circles at the same time

You might be able to skip the paint and just put the paper on something slightly soft (a small thin cardboard sheet that you move as you move the can, like from a breakfast cereal box) behind and then press the can down hard leaving an impression in the paper - you say it's for a guide as to where to glue other things, so not having the paper surface contaminated with paint will probably aid adhesion whereas a layer of paint then means you've got your things glued to your paint, which is stuck to your paper ie two stages of glueing and more likely to fail

Answer (score 0):

A hands on cheap method:

Cut a disk of the right size out of a sponge. A thin sponge cloth as used in doing dishes will do, a thicker one will also work.
Put a thin layer of paint on a plate, put your sponge disk in the paint and then use it to mark your spots.
Try it on a spare piece of paper, to see how much paint you need and how much presure, both taking up paint and releasing it.
You will need to add to the paint in the plate as you use it.

For freehand work that is all you need. It will be more tidy if you mark out where to place the dots.

Use gloves and/or paint you can wash off you hands.
Back in school we used string glued to a bit of wood with a handle. If you need to do many spots you can also do that or glue the sponge to a backing and handle.

Answer (score 0):

- take an awl.
- tie a rope to it.
- to the other end of the rope, at the required distance,
  tie a pencil.
- stick an awl into a sheet of paper.
- twist a pencil around it.
- voila !!! )))
- ps: to reduce the length of the radius
  you need to wind the rope around the pencil

Comment: For 60mm (less than 2 1/2")  compasses are easier and more accurate.